# How to increase a circle along with increasing the text inside the circle?

Tags: html, css

I want to have text inside a circle. Is it possible to dynamically increase the size of the circle when the text increases?
[This is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/mLW47).
But the problem for me in this example is that only the width increases along with the text.

e.g

```css
.badge {
    background:             radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px );
        background:    -moz-radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px );
        background:     -ms-radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px );
        background:      -o-radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px );
        background: -webkit-radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px );
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px; /* one half of ( (border * 2) + height + padding ) */
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    color: white;
    font: bold 15px/13px Helvetica, Verdana, Tahoma;
    height: 16px; 
    padding: 4px 3px 0 3px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 14px;
}

/* only needed for this sample */
.badge {
    float: left;
    left: 25px;
    margin: 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="badge">1</div>
<div class="badge">2</div>
<div class="badge">3</div>
<div class="badge">44</div>
<div class="badge">55</div>
<div class="badge">666</div>
<div class="badge">777</div>
<div class="badge">8888</div>
<div class="badge">9999</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to use javascript to adjust the height to match the width; you should also use 50% for the border-radius.  I have modified [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/trr2R/<br).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){$('.badge').each(function(){
    $(this).height($(this).width());
    $(this).css('line-height', $(this).height()+'px');
})});
```

```css
.badge {
    background:             radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px );
        background:    -moz-radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px );
        background:     -ms-radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px );
        background:      -o-radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px );
        background: -webkit-radial-gradient( 5px -9px, circle, white 8%, red 26px );
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%; /* one half of ( (border * 2) + height + padding ) */
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    color: white;
    font: bold 15px/13px Helvetica, Verdana, Tahoma;
    height: 16px; 
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 16px;
}

/* only needed for this sample */
.badge {
    float: left;
    left: 25px;
    margin: 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="badge">1</div>
<div class="badge">2</div>
<div class="badge">3</div>
<div class="badge">44</div>
<div class="badge">55</div>
<div class="badge">666</div>
<div class="badge">777</div>
<div class="badge">8888</div>
<div class="badge">9999</div>
```

Comment: Or if you use a specific font you can know ahead of time how wide (and tall) everything needs to be.

Comment: @reisio: Only if that is a bitmap font you provide for download. People do have different versions of fonts, and operating systems render fonts differently. (Most well-known of the latter: OS X usually obeys the given font sizes, which makes them look smaller than on Windows, where font sizes given in pt are generally scaled up by a factor I never can remember.)

Comment: No any type of font, just as long as you provide it.  The small rendering differences across operating systems is easily compensated for.